# How to add and remove table form rows using Angular?

Tags: angular, forms

I am attempting to create an Angular Form that incorporates tables with the capability to dynamically add and remove rows, similar to the one depicted in the image.
[image]

I have developed an Angular form, but I am having difficulty writing the necessary functions to send the form data to the backend. The backend has been implemented successfully, so the problem lies in the frontend code.

Since, taxRateDetailsForm is an array form, how can I access its form rows and properly POST them to the backend?
Here, is my GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/purushottamnawale/Tax-Authority-CRUD)

**add-tax-rate.component.html:**

```
<tbody [formGroup]="taxRateDetilsForm">
    <ng-container formArrayName="tableRows" *ngFor="let group of getFormControls.controls; let i=index">
        <tr [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>
                <div class="my-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" (click)="addRow()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-plus" style="color: #b95bf2;"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" (click)="removeEmployee(i)"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-minus" style="color: #f11616;"></i></button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col form-group my-4">
                    <input formControlName="hsn_sac_no" type="text" name="hsn_sac_no" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Hsn sac no">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col form-group my-4">
                    <input formControlName="description" type="text" name="description" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="description">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col form-group my-4">
                    <input formControlName="from_date" type="date" name="from_date" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="From Date">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col form-group my-4">
                    <input formControlName="to_date" type="date" name="to_date" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="To Date">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col form-group my-4">
                    <input formControlName="tax_rate" type="number" name="tax_rate" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Tax Rate">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col form-group my-4">
                    <label class="form-check-label form-control-sm" for="rcm_flag" id="active_tax_details">Inactive</label>
                    <!-- <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="taxRateDetilsForm.get('rcm_flag')!.value" (change)="toggle2($event)" class="smaller-slide-toggle" id="mat-slider"></mat-slide-toggle> -->
                    <!-- <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="group.get('rcm_flag')!.value" (change)="toggle2($event)" class="smaller-slide-toggle" id="mat-slider"></mat-slide-toggle> -->
                    <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="rcm_flag" (change)="toggle2($event)" class="smaller-slide-toggle" id="mat-slider"></mat-slide-toggle>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="rcm_flag" id="inactive_tax_details">Active</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col form-group my-4">
                    <input formControlName="cess" type="number" name="cess" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Cess">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

**add-tax-rate-component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-tax-rate',
  templateUrl: './add-tax-rate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-tax-rate.component.css'],
})
export class AddTaxRateComponent {
  public taxRateDetailsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private service: TaxRateService, private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.taxRateDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
      tableRows: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required])
    });
    this.addRow();
  }

  createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      header_ref_id: new FormControl<number | null>(null, Validators.required),
      hsn_sac_no: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      from_date: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
      to_date: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
      tax_rate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      rcm_flag: new FormControl(true,),
      cess: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

    });
  }

  get getFormControls() {
    const control = this.taxRateDetailsForm.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    return control;
  }

  addRow() {
    const control = this.taxRateDetailsForm.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    const taxRatePK = this.TaxRateList ? this.TaxRateList[0].pk : null;
    control.push(this.createFormGroup());
  }

  removeEmployee(index: number) {
    const control = this.taxRateDetailsForm.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    control.removeAt(index);
  }

  TaxAuthorityList: any;
  TaxRateList: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshList();
  }

  refreshList() {
    this.service.getTaxAuthority().subscribe((data: Tax[]) => {
      // console.log(data);
      this.TaxAuthorityList = data;
      this.TaxAuthorityList.forEach((taxauthority: Tax) => {
        console.log(taxauthority.pk, taxauthority.name);
      });
    });

    
    this.service.getTaxRatePK().subscribe((data: TaxRatePK[]) => {
      // console.log(data);
      this.TaxRateList = data;
      this.TaxRateList.forEach((taxrate: TaxRatePK) => {
        // console.log(taxrate.pk, taxrate.tax_rate_name);
        this.taxRateDetailsForm.patchValue({
          header_ref_id: taxrate.pk
        });
      });
    });  
  }

  data: any

  form1 = new FormGroup({
    tax_rate_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    tax_authority_ref_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    tax_type_ref_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    is_active: new FormControl(true),
  });


    addTaxRate() {
    const form1Data = this.form1.value;
    const form2Data: any[] = [];
  
    const control = this.taxRateDetailsForm.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    control.controls.forEach((group: AbstractControl<any, any>) => {
      if (group instanceof FormGroup) {
        form2Data.push(group.value);
      }
    });
  
    this.service.addTaxRate(form1Data).subscribe(() => {
      this.service.addTaxRateDetails({ data: form2Data }).subscribe(() => {
        // Both form1 and form2 data have been successfully submitted
        this.router.navigate(['/viewtaxrate']);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

**Edit: I have found a solution to my problem. The implementation can be found on GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/purushottamnawale/Tax-Authority-CRUD).**

Comment: its Angular (have no related about Angularjs). About mat-slide, you can use also formControlName:`<mat-slide-toggle formControlName="rcm_flag">`, about your question, really it's not clear for me what is your problem. If is how create the FormGroup using the data received from a service you can use some similar to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68447554/dynamic-id-in-formarray-angular/68532995#68532995)

Comment: Check this example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-remove-controls-from-form-group-of-form-adzpv1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts